# 406 HTTP Status for custom accept/header and return type in Spring REST API

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jaxb

I have a Spring REST API which must respond for custom 'accept: project/xml' header. Moreover, I'm returning own Response object from the REST method which should be converted to XML then (so as all responses be wrapped inside  tag).
So, the Controller looks like:

```
@Controller("Project Controller")
@RequestMapping(value = "/wa", produces = "project/xml; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public class ProjectController {

    private final IProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    public ProjectController(IProjectService projectService) {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response projectInfo() {
        return new Response(projectService.listProjects());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response start() {
        return new Response(new JAXBElement<>(new QName("resource"), 
String.class, StaticConstants.STRING_START_TAG));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/end", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> end() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(StaticConstants.STRING_END_TAG);
    }
}
```

This is how the Response class looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Response {

   @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
   private List<Object> body;

   public Response(Object single) {
      if (body == null) {
          body = new ArrayList<>(1);
      }
      body.add(single);
   }
}
```

All Bean classes that are wrapped inside Response are also marked with @XmlRootElement and @XmlElement annotations everywhere.

I've included all fasterxml dependencies also (even those that are not necessary):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also I've added necessary bean to Spring config, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project")
public class BeanConfiguration {

    ...

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

The issue is that I'm receiving **406 Not Acceptable** Status for /start endpoint, but don't receive it for /end endpoint.
The request I'm sending from Postman contains 'Accept: project/xml' header, of course.

So, everything works if I remove 'produces' from Controller and 'Accept' header from the Postman request. 
Also it works if I change 'produces' to 'application/xml' and the request header to 'application/xml' or without any header.

But using custom header it works only with **ResponseEntity** class and doesn't work for my own **Response** class.

I've also tried the to make Response class extend ResponseEntity, but no effect.

I've looked through many solutions and similar questions - nothing helps. And nobody else is using own, custom 'Accept' header.

Comment: How does your `project/xml` differ from any generic `application/xml` media type? Why don't you stick with `application/vnd.some-project+xml`?

Comment: It doesn't differ. I'm implementing the API which will be used by another application which itself uses this 'project/xml' accept header and this can't be changed. There's another word instead of 'project', but I can't share it.

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually managed to fix this issue the next way. Firstly, added own message converter which extends `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` and call `setSupportedMediaTypes` method:

```
public class ProjectXmlMessageConverter extends Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter {

    public ProjectXmlMessageConverter() {
        super();
        setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.valueOf("project/xml")));
}
```

}

Secondly, added my converter to list of already defined converters this way:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ProjectXmlMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

Now it works and my API responses to requests with 'Accept: project/xml' header.